# How to customize file upload object with special text in the box?

Tags: javascript, file, input

```
<input type="file" id="file">
```

The simple html label created the below box and characters inside and around it.

[image]

Now i want to customize the logo into the below.

[image]

1.to remove characters `No file selected.`.
2.to change characters `Browse...` in the box into `upload`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options to do it:

**Option 1: Use label**

```css
 label{
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: #e0e6eb;
 }
 label:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
 }
```

```html
<label for="file">Upload</label>
<input type="file" id="file" style="display: none;">
```

**Option 2: You can use jQuery.**

I usually use this way for my website. It's very simple.
Assume you have 2 elements. A, B.

Step 1: You will click A - $('A').click

Step 2: Trigger B - $('B').trigger('click').

A is an html element

B is `<input type="file" id="file">`

That's it.